# C++ cast syntax

Tags: c++, casting

I've never seen the following cast syntax:

> int var = int(1.0);

int is a base type so I'm wondering: is it equivalent to

> int var = (int)1.0;

?

Comment: Think of `int(1.0)` as a constructor call.

Comment: It is the same, the only difference is the first one will not work in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two notations are equivalent(in the case of primitive types). Just a side note: please use static_cast in `c++` instead of C-style casting. Does not make too much difference here but this is a bad habit.

For complex types first one would be calling a constructor while the second one is calling a casting operator and thus they may have quite different logic.

Comment: Thank you, I just had a simple doubt.

Comment: Can you expand on the "in this case"? IMO, without the explanation, that small specification does more harm than good.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I have changed it to in the case of primitive types. hope this sounds better.

Comment: Ok, what if they are not primitive types? How is it different?

Answer (score 1):

The first call is a constructor call.. The second is casting. They are basically the same.

Comment: so primitive types are classes too? I don't understand

Comment: @JohnnyPauling not really, they are primitives, but they can still be regarded as classes, they have their own operators and so on. If you write your own class Int and compare its assembly to that of the primitive int, it will be identical.

Comment: its called constructor initialization more like `type identifier (initial_value) ; `

Comment: It looks like a constructor call. But technically it is a cast operation. But personally I like to think of the as POD constructors (if it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck its a duck).

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions are syntactically correct and equivalent methods of explicit type casting. 
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/